# My JPanel doesn't doesn't show up consistently

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I'm a relatively young programmer and I'm having a problem. When ever I try to run my program on the custom `JPanel` I made doesn't show up most of the time and when it does show up it and I try to run it again with the exact same code it doesn't work.

Can someone please help me?

```
package ca.Software.PocketUniverse;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MercuryMain extends JFrame {
ImageIcon windowicon;

public MercuryMain(){
windowsetup();
}

public void windowsetup(){
JFrame j=new JFrame();
windowicon= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("mercury.jpg"));
this.setTitle("MercuryMessaging");
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);
this.pack();
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setIconImage(windowicon.getImage());
ContentPanel p=new ContentPanel();
JButton b=new JButton("code");
p.add(b);
add(p);
}

public void errormethod(){
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MercuryMain();
}
}
```

### ContentPanel

```
package ca.Software.PocketUniverse;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
public class ContentPanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JButton contacts;

public ContentPanel(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contacts=new JButton("contacts");
    this.add(contacts,BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
}
```

Comment: Invoke `setVisible()` _last_ in `windowsetup()`, and see [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Thanks for the help i'll keep these tips in mind